# Find by PK in Django model

Tags: python, django, lookup

I'm working in a django view for AUTHOR, I first need to pull up all the authors. Next I need to leverage another model (Book - which is included in the view), and for each author, I want to find the books they've written that are active.

The Book model has a foreign key to the Author (the author ID or primary Key)

I've got this below ... but it's not working and I'm stumped - any thoughts?

```
def authors(request):
   _vars = {}
    authors = Author.objects.all()

    #loop through the authors
    for author in authors.object_list:
        books = Book.objects.filter(author=author.pk).filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('-author__author_type__importance').exclude(author__is_active=False)
        author.append(books)

    _vars['authors'] = authors

    return render(request, 'template.html', _vars)
```

Sorry: to clarify - I'm unable to run this in debug mode, I am doing this (stupidly) on a live environment.

The server responds with a 500 error and I'm kinda blind as to why. It is this line

```
        books = Book.objects.filter(author=author.pk).filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('-author__author_type__importance').exclude(author__is_active=False)
```

And my suspicion is the primary key lookup. I use the exact same search in a specific Author look up and it works - but when I try to reference the primary key in the for loop it fails

What I want is this to return a list of all the authors (id, name, age etc from my author model) along with a list of their books (book id, book name etc)

I'd have an object where I can go author.name (this is the authors name) or author.books.name (get the name of the book - well it'd be a set of books so I'd need to iterate through - but you get the idea right?)

The template might look like

```
{% for author in authors %}
    Name: {{ author.name }}
    Age: {{ author.age }}
    {% for book in author.books %}
        Title: {{ book.title }}
        Published: {{ book.published }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please write the wrong output and what is your expactation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Use

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author=author)filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('-author__author_type__importance').exclude(author__is_active=False)
```

Or use

```
books = Book.objects.filter(author__id=author.id)filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('-author__author_type__importance').exclude(author__is_active=False)
```

Both will work

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the results of this query to the template:

```
 books = Book.objects.filter(author=author.pk).filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('-author__author_type__importance').exclude(author__is_active=False)
```

(Also, you shouldn't need both `filter(author__is_active=True)` and `exclude(author__is_active=False`).

Personally, I would do something like

```
books = Books.objects.all().filter(is_active=True, author__is_active=True).order_by('author')
```

Pass it to the template:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', {'books': books})
```

or

```
return render(request, 'template.html', locals())
```

And in the template:

```
{% for b in books %}
    Author: {{ b.author.name }}
    Title: {{ b.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

or something similar

Comment: Sorry I missed that out (will edit that) ... it's not that though that's causing it to fail (I'm running in a non-debug space) the book call in the for loop fails (server throws 500) ... I suspect it's because it can't get the author.pk

Comment: yeah - its not quite where I'm going with it ... I'll update the question with a template example of what I'm looking to do

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it ...

I threw the block out and started again, nice and simple

```
for author in authors:
    author.books = ''
    books = Book.objects.filter(author=author, is_active=True)
    author.books = books
```

And what do you know ... it works.
Thanks everyone for their help!

Comment: Awesome!
You could also make the book query using `author.books = author.book_set.filter(is_active=True)`, as per [Related Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)